# AWS cloudwatch node.js metrics send performance concern

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am new to using aws-sdk in a node.js project. I was going through the guide mentioned [here](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javascriptv3/example_code/cloudwatch/src/putMetricData.js) about sending metrics to AWS cloudwatch. The example below in particular uses a promise based approach for sending metrics, if i am to use the below strategy for sending metrics, for e.g. whenever a particular endpoint is triggered, how performant will this usage be?

Node.js runtime is single threaded, so, for every request adding something on the call stack for a single threaded process seems like a performance degrading practice, in Java you could use daemon threads for sending metrics.

Should this be a concern? If yes, then what could be a better strategy for sending the metrics?

```
export const run = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await cwClient.send(new PutMetricDataCommand(params));
    console.log("Success", data.$metadata.requestId);
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by batching metrics and making a single call periodically.
You can try the aws-embedded-metrics library for nodejs. I have not used this but looks like you can flush the metrics periodically.